# What message is sent to the window when user click X on top bar to close the app

Tags: c++, c, linux, x11, cinnamon

When a user click on top bar X button to close the window (the one near minimize and maximize buttons) what message is received by the app?
In windows is a WM_CLOSE, what about in Linux? I use Linux Mint.

Comment: I'm very interested for the applications that do not run in a console

Comment: None of the tags you selected help, I would suggest 'x11'.